# VBA WORD. Отформатировать текст в ячейке пробелами

Tags: vba, макросы

Как с помощью макроса отформатировать текст в ячейке согласно требованию?
Первая ячейка - исходные данные, вторая ячейка - ожидаемый результат.
"Вручную" делается так:

1. поместить курсор в ячейку
2. удалить (если есть) пробелы сначала и в конце текста из ячейки
3. поместить курсор перед вторым справа словом и вставлять пробел пока конец строки не достиг конца ячейки. Переход текста на другую строку ячейки не допускается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Sub IdentifyCurrentCell()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim cell As cell
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim outputText As String

    
    ' Проверка что курсор внутри таблицы
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        ' Получаем таблицу
        Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1) 
        
        ' Ищем активную ячейку
        For Each cell In tbl.Range.Cells
            If Selection.Range.InRange(cell.Range) Then
                ' курсор здес
                MsgBox "Cursor is in Row " & cell.RowIndex & ", Column " & cell.ColumnIndex
                cellText = Trim(cell.Range.Text)
                
                ' Удаляем подвоение пробелов
                Do
                    outputText = cellText
                    cellText = Replace(cellText, "  ", " ")
                Loop Until cellText = outputText
                
                ' КОД ЗДЕСЬ ?
                            
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        MsgBox "Cursor is not within a table."
    End If
End Sub
```